# One character only is being returned when using foreach phpfox

Tags: arrays, database, foreach, phpfox

I am trying to get some data from a table but when i use foreach it returns only 1 character or the 1st letter/number and one row is returned.

Here is my code.
home.class.php

```
public function getData()
{   
        $aRow = $this->database()->select('*')
                                 ->from('tablename')        
                                 ->execute('getSlaveRow');      

                 return $aRow;
 }
```

ajax.class.php

```
    public function getArr()
    {
            $data = 'No data found';
            $results = Phpfox::getService('files.home')->getData();

            if($results) {
                $data = '<div id="fileparse" style="height:295px;overflow:auto;display:none;"</div>';
                $data .= '<div id="filelist" style="height:295px;overflow:auto;">';
                $data .= '<table style="width:100%;"><tr><td><b>File Name</b></td><td>                                  <b>Account Type</b></td><td><b>Account Number</b></td><td><b>Company</b></td><td><b>Results</b></td></tr>';

                foreach($results as $result) {

                    $data .= '<tr>';                

                    $data .= '<td>'.$result['file'].'</td>';  

                     $data .= '<td>'.$result['result'].'</td>';                              
                     $data .= '</tr>';                  
                }

                $data .= '</table>';
                $data .= '</div>';
            } else
                $data = 'No results found';


            $this->html('#eqblock', $data); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use getSlaveRows insted of getSlaveRow

getSlaveRow return single array while getSlaveRows return all rows